# Are there personal finance applications offering both an iPhone and a mac version?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, mac

With the demise of Cha-ching, I find myself in need of an application for managing my expenses which I can use on both platforms.
It should work in Europe, and maybe have a decent UI.

Answer (score 5):

Add [MoneyWell](http://nothirst.com/moneywell/) to the list

Comment: I use MoneyWell myself, but it's compatibility with "European" banks is limited or nonexistent. (And I haven't found an app that does it)

Comment: @Martin I've mostly given up on “automatic” bank integration (this is also my bank's fault).

Comment: @Agos indeed, most of these programas are made in the USA, and even those who are made elsewhere support the same standards. Most of the crappy banks in the EU do not support that type of integration. (I have yet to come across one in Spain that does it…)

Answer (score 2):

You have [iCompta](http://www.lyricapps.com/iCompta/) which is the one I use. Well followed by its developer, with upgrades and a quick support through dedicated forum.
I must admit I was used to Money on PC and wanted to have something which doesn't change my (good or bad) habits too much. It's a good one for this.

Answer (score 1):

[iBank](http://www.iggsoftware.com/ibank/index.php) and [SplashMoney](http://www.splashdata.com/splashmoney/) do what you want. I haven't tested either.
iBank looks like a nicer interface, but costs a lot more.

Comment: I've tried iBank and ditched it because of its (at the time, at least) poor transaction download feature. I was used to an easy reconciliation process, and it was cumbersome. The interface is also somewhat chunky.

Answer (score 1):

Not an application but [mint.com](http://www.mint.com/) runs in any browser on the desktop and has an iPhone app. Mint is like throwing all of you money up in the air and it lands in neat little stacks with labels. Mint is free.

I have no affiliation with Mint, I just like it.

Comment: Unfortunately mint.com is only available in the USA and in Canada.

Comment: Mint also does *not* allow you to enter transactions proactively, or otherwise alter the register. All information in Mint has to be downloaded from a financial institution.

Comment: That's not true. It was updated a few months ago to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

iBank is a very good desktop application and I found it to be a more than adequate replacement for Microsoft Money when I moved to the Mac.

There is a companion iPhone app which I haven't used yet, but apparently it can sync to the desktop app via WiFi (Bonjour), MobileMe and any WebDAV server. (If they supported DropBox it would be ideal for me and I'd have bought it by now).

(Edit: I should add that I downloaded and evaluated iBank against MoneyWell - for me iBank won hands down though for the life of me now I can't remember why. I think the overall experience just seemed better).

HTH,

Maurice

Answer (score 0):

I use [You Need a Budget](http://www.youneedabudget.com/). It's a great little app, and also has a mobile version that is really nice.

Comment: Interesting. The “Get Out of Debt” tagline isn't really inviting, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Agos: Yeah, admittedly it has a somewhat annoying motif geared towards keeping you out of debt, but I've found the budgeting tools to be really nice, and it generates good reports/graphs. You just have to ignore the "here're some tips for saving and reducing debt" stuff if you're not deeply in debt.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out http://www.squirrelapp.com/, which looks quite bare-bones, but has the required features.