# Finance App That Charts Bank Info?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, mac-appstore, ios-appstore

I'm looking for a finance app that will connect to my banks so I can see My balance at the end of every day, week, month.  I would like to see how it rises and falls just so I can keep a better eye on my money.  Are there any dashboards or apps like this?

If there is an app that syncs with an iOS app that would be great

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100220/what-os-x-and-ios-software-combination-tracks-finances?lq=1 for a fairly thorough list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Mint.com does exactly that:
https://www.mint.com/how-it-works/accounts/

They have a website as well as iPhone and iPad apps.