# Software to track income and spending on OS X and Android

Tags: software-recommendation

There is this other question that asks about [What OS X and iOS software combination tracks finances?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100220/what-os-x-and-ios-software-combination-tracks-finances)

But most of the software listed there is much to powerful (and complicated) for me. I just tried out the demo for YNAB, but I can't get my head around that software. What the hell is a budget, anyway?

All I want is a very simple tool that allows me to:

- begin with a starting balance
- enter monthly income (salary)
- enter monthly expenses (rent, health insurance, telephone)
- *optional:* with date
- *optional:* quarterly / yearly payments
- *optional:* enter an end date for these monthly monetary flows (e.g. a loan that will be paid at a certain date)
- enter spendings on my mobile phone as they happen
- calculate a live balance and display it

I don't want to:

- track stocks
- create a savings plan
- connect to my bank account
- any other stuff

Plus:

- looks nice
- exports / saves to file in a format that other software can read (e.g. csv, MySQL database)

I would use an Excel sheet, if I didn't want to use it on my mobile phone.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's not mac specific, but I'd recommend checking out [Mint.com](https://www.mint.com/).  I was originally skeptical of letting a service connect to my bank accounts, but after using for a little while I am now a believer.   If you categorize your transactions for a month or two it learns, and you'll find that you need to spend less and less time manually entering data.

Comment: I'm not in the US (nor Canada) and cannot use Mint. I need software that does not require a US bank account.